# mysql Command timeout error

Tags: sql, mysql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005

I am converting my database from SQL Server 2005 to MySQL using asp .net mvc.

I have bulk data in SQL Server (400k records), but I am facing command timeout/waiting for `CommandTimeout` error which, when I search on Google, can be given 65535 as its highest value or 0 (if it should wait for unlimited time).

Both of these aren't working for me. I also have set any `ConnectTimeout` to 180. So should I have to change it too? Anybody who had faced this problem or have any confirmed knowledge please share.

Comment: Which have you set, the ConnectionTimeout or the CommandTimeout(have to be set on each individual MySqlCommand objects) ? What did you set them to, and what happened (specifically, what happened including any error messages etc.)?

Comment: As i have written coonect timeout i have set in web.config to 180 & command timeout in my method call to 65535.

Answer (score 2):

For me increasing the CommandTimeout fixed the issue.

Code sample:

```
//time in seconds
int timeOut = 300;
//create command
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(stringSQL);
//set timeout
myCommand.CommandTimeout = timeOut;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try sending commands in a batch of 100/500 then there will be no need of command timeout. Hope it works for you